# How can I get ranking of records by the column of associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**`User`** has one **`UserProfile`**, and **`UserProfile`** belongs to **`User`**

There is a column called `total_point` in **`UserProfile`** table.
and I'd like to sort by this column.

so I tried this but I get this error. Why? How can I modify?

**Error**

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

**Controller**

```
@rank = User.confirmed.joins(:user_profile).order('user_profiles.total_point ASC').index(current_user)
```

**View**

```
Rank: <%= @rank %>
```

Comment: `.index(current_user)`? What's that for? What should `@rank` output? The `total_point` for a single user?

Comment: @DamienRoche Not for single user. I want the rank of all users with scope

Comment: @DamienRoche It's taking forever to load now:(

Comment: Ignore that last comment! I can see what you're trying to do, and `index(current_user)` should be working. Is the error you included on that particular line? Could you include the full error message?

Comment: The reason this isn't working is because you're calling `index` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but you need to convert to an array -- `all.index(current_user)`. However, this is highly inefficient because it will load all your users into an array before fetching the index. You should look into maintaining the rank in some other way, maybe with a rank column, or something like redis.

Comment: @DamienRoche wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)): the same:(

Comment: @DamienRoche It makes sense now:) Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

If this order behaviour is going to be used across a number of views, you'd be better off placing this logic in the model to keep your views clean:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   default_scope joins(:user_profile).order('user_profiles.total_point ASC')

end
```

This default logic can also be overridden, when required, by just calling the order method mentioned above on your collection/array. It's good to get into the habit of keeping the majority of the business logic in your models/library.